# Thread ocupando muita memoria

Tags: c#, thread, memória, controles

Vamos lá . Eu estou carregando Buttons em um painel através do BackGroundWorker . Ou seja , dentro deste BackGround eu executo uma consulta no banco através do EF e preencho o painel com os Buttons que contem informações provenientes desta consulta . Quanto mais vezes a thread roda , mais memoria ele aloca . O que eu faço para impedir que esse consumo cresça tanto ?

Aqui esta o codigo do BackGroundWorker

```
private void WorkCarregaVendas_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                CarregaVendasAtivas();

                    CarregaMesas();
                    CarregaDeliverys();



                ExecutaPesquisaNumero(txtPesquisaNumero.Text, true);

            }));
         Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

    }
```

Aqui que eu carrego os botões .

```
private void CarregaMesas()
    {

        foreach (BotaoOperacional Control in flMesas.Controls)
        {
            Control.Dispose();
        }

        flMesas.Controls.Clear();

        //Pois se há uma pesquisa não a necessidade de carregar todos . 
        if (txtPesquisaNumero.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
            foreach (var mesaCliente in objListaVendasAtivas.Where(x => x.IdTipoVenda == (int)EnumTipoVenda.Mesa).OrderBy(x => x.NumeroMesa))
            {
                decimal preco = 0;
                using (var insRepositorioMesaProduto = new MesaProdutoRepositorio())
                {
                    preco = insRepositorioMesaProduto.
                        PesquisaProdutoMesa(mesaCliente.Id).Select(x => x.Produto)
                        .Sum(x => x.PrecoVenda);
                }
                var btn = new BotaoOperacional(mesaCliente)
                {
                    AtualizarMenuPrincipal = CarregaMesas,
                    Aparencia = EnumTipoVenda.Mesa,
                    NumeroMesa = mesaCliente.NumeroMesa,
                    Cliente = mesaCliente.Cliente == null ? "" : mesaCliente.Cliente.Descricao,
                    Preco = preco
                };



                btn.CarregaBotao();

                flMesas.Controls.Add(btn);


            }

    }
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o trecho de código em que você instancia os botões a partir dos resultados da sua consulta. Só assim alguém poderá verificar se por acaso você não está deixando botões alocados de consultas prévias (o que poderia indicar o aumento do consumo de memória).

Comment: Luiz ja adicionei o codigo a pergunta .

Comment: Quem executa `WorkCarregaVendas_DoWork`? Por que ele tem um laço infinito (`while (true)`), se a ideia (aparente) seria apenas carregar as informações e terminar? Como você sabe que o vazamento de memória não está nas outras chamadas (`CarregaVendasAtivas();` ou `CarregaDeliverys();`, por exemplo)? E o que faz `btn.CarregaBotao()`? Infelizmente tem muitos locais onde pode haver problemas. Vc tentou restringir o código (comentando) pra tentar descobrinr onde exatamente ocorre o problema?

Comment: como o @LuizVieira opontou, um `while (true)` com um `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));` não me parece saudavel... você poderia tentar usar um `System.Timers.Timer` como no exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6mkoA5

Answer (score 4):

#### No geral

Para saber de onde o que está causando o aumento indesejado do consumo de memória, o melhor a fazer é rodar um [profile](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/profilers) da aplicação. Pode ser que o vazamento está vindo dessa thread, pode ser que está vindo de outro lugar. Só com uma visão de "dentro" para responder.

O processo é, basicamente:

1. Detectar quais objetos *indesejados* não estão sendo liberados;
2. Rastrear os pontos de criação desses objetos;
3. Rastrear os pontos de destruição desses objetos;
4. Rastrear os pontos de referência desses objetos.

O (2) é para colocar *breakpoints* e ver quais chamadas ocasionam a criação dos objetos, e (3) e (4) são rastreamentos posteriores, ver em que pontos esses objetos deveriam estar sendo destruídos (e não estão sendo) ou em que pontos os objetos estão sendo referenciados (e não deveriam estar sendo). Objetos referenciados não são destruídos.

#### *using* para limpar memória

Um erro clássico, a olhar, é se está utilizando `using(){}` em todos os objetos que podem (ou devem) ser descartados deterministicamente.

Você mencionou que está usando EF. Em todos os pontos que cria o objeto de contexto, está utilizando um idioma desse tipo?

```
using ( var ef = new SeuContexto() )
{
    ...
}
```

#### Situação normal, em princípio

Isso tudo dito, o que você está observando *é o normal*. O *garbage collector* não roda continuamente, e mesmo quando roda, não é sempre que roda uma versão que [diminui a memória aparente do programa](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/276585/when-is-it-a-good-idea-to-force-garbage-collection#276593).

*Gen 2 Collections* podem ser executados com diferenças de vários minutos entre si. Ou seja, o tipo de GC que baixa memória só ocorre de quando em quando.

Um aumento de memória só é considerado "muito" ou "problema" quando a memória do programa não estabiliza *nunca*. A memória subir por vários minutos para depois cair é mais ou menos o comportamento esperado.

Comment: Adicionei o codigo .

Comment: O grande problema é que quando a memoria chega a 50 mb o sistema gera uma exception (Referencia de objeto sem uma instancia de objeto).

Comment: É coincidência. NullPointerException geralmente não é problema de memória, e sim de código. E o código postado faz umas coisas esquisitas, BeginInvoke [sem EndInvole](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492741/c-sharp-asynchronous-call-without-endinvoke), o que pode derrubar a aplicação; Chama Dispose explicitamente (o que faz ele ser chamado duas vezes no total). NPE você tem de debugar, ou ao menos gravar (logar) as exceções para estudar depois.